# How to change the width of the textLabel in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have several `UITableViewCell`'s that have custom buttons in them. These buttons cover up the text in a few of the cells. How do I set the width of the `textLabel` attribute within the cell so this doesn't happen? This doesn't seem to work.

```
cell.textLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16)
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap
cell.textLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200
```

I am running this in the `tableView(table_view, willDisplayCell:cell, forRowAtIndexPath:index_path)` method.

Setting the frame at this time doesn't work either.

Comment: Is it not perhaps easier to subclass UITableViewCell or UIView and craft it this way instead?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm unsure as to why it doesn't work. Are the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` and `frame` frozen at this point?

Comment: I believe textLabel's frame is read-only

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was able to add the text to a `UILabel` (set up how I needed it) and add that label to the `contentView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your `UITableViewCell`s to look better than the default behavior, you should probably draw the complete contents, so your custom buttons and the text and probably other information, in a view subclass of your own and return that as the view for the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Probably create/alloc a UILabel and add it to the cell instead. That way you can set its frame.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.